# mysql query with php variable and "%"

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Fallo al contenctar a MySQL: ("
         . $mysqli->connect_errno
         . ") "
         . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$resultado = $mysqli->query('select title FROM 4d_topics 
                             where title Like "B%" and forum_id=174');

$row_cnt = $resultado->num_rows;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $row_cnt; $i++) {
    $resultado->data_seek($i);
    $row = $resultado->fetch_row();
    printf ($row[0]);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

And that works, but, how can i change "B" with a php variable (like... $letter) which contains a letter?

For example...

```
$resultado = $mysqli->query('select title FROM 4d_topics 
                             where title Like **"$Letter%"** and forum_id=174');
```

Comment: Are you asking about string concatenation? Try, `$resultado = $mysqli->query('select title FROM 4d_topics where title Like %' . $Letter . '% and forum_id=174');` Kinda weird how you know how to echo the error message with brackets. [Here's a good read](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code (puedes usar este código):

```
$letter = 'B';
$resultado = $mysqli->query('select title FROM 4d_topics where title Like "'.$letter.'%" and forum_id=174');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function searching_letter($value){
    return $mysqli->query('select title FROM 4d_topics 
                         where title Like '.$value.' and forum_id=174');
}

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Fallo al contenctar a MySQL: ("
         . $mysqli->connect_errno
         . ") "
         . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$value = 'B%';
$resultado = searching_letter($value);

$row_cnt = $resultado->num_rows;
for ($i = 0; $i <= $row_cnt; $i++) {
    $resultado->data_seek($i);
    $row = $resultado->fetch_row();
    printf ($row[0]);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

with this code you can change the like from the start `%B` or `%B%` or `B%`